# hidden_field value default value is overridden by cached value

Tags: html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, hidden-field

No matter what I do in my code, the value of my hidden field is always "1". I've tried setting it in my code via ERB, HTML, and jQuery, but the only thing that's worked is jQuery in my Javascript console. Nothing I do in my actual code base affects it.

I'd like for it to start with a value of nil and set it to an integer using JS, but I'd settle for being able to change it from "1" at all.

Here's the ERB I tried:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "id", nil, id:"id-field" %>
```

Here's the HTML I tried:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id-field" value="0">
```

Here's the jQuery I tried:

```
$("#id-field").val(47);
```

But that all results in this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id-field" value="1">
```

Like I said, if I run the jQuery in my console, I can finally change the value. What's going on?

UPDATE:

It's definitely a caching issue. I set the value to "1" once, and I can't get the default to change, although my syntax is definitely correct. Anyone have similar troubles with the value attribute of a hidden field? (I'm trying hidden_field instead of hidden_field_tag but the behavior is the same)

This is the erb I'm using, and the `value` does work initially, but when I set the value to something else and refresh, the cached value is applied and the `value` attribute is completely ignored.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :id, value: @id, id: "id-field" %>
```

Comment: do you get it's value as `1` when you submit form or you get `1` set as value on the page itself when page get's rendered?

Comment: it’s not that useless if you think about the possibility to change a hidden field with JS

we are not getting the value when we set the hidden_field_tag, instead, it is a String that we are getting.

Comment: @AmitPatel Both. It's "1" in the rendered HTML and in the submitted params.

Comment: @HanyMoh. Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I wanted to get close to the issue. I had doubt about JS was changing value before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var field = $('input[name="id"]:hidden');
field.val('45');
```